# PHP: Session id storing in database doesn't work

Tags: php

I have this code to store the session_id in a database:

```
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$false = 0;
$id = session_id();

$sql = "INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
if($query = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ssssii', $username, $password2, $email, $naam, $false, $id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

And I store it in a varchar(32) column. But after the storage, it contains just the first 2 characters. Why is this?

Comment: have you tried printing it `echo $name;` and `die();` to see variable by variable data. can you do this

Comment: You are binding the last parameter as an integer, you need `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ssssis', ...`

Comment: @MadhuNair Yeah, already done. The variable is fine.

Comment: @jeroen Jep, that was it. Thank you.

Comment: @MadhuNair the issue is with the session ID, not the name, and anyway there isn't even a variable `$name` in the code at all...

Comment: an integer in php is 32 bits or 4 bytes long, which is as long as 2 unicode characters